# Auto fill visible cells (filtered range) with specific string - using Vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Need to filter column C to search text content like "sim" if content found then fill cell of column B

```
   Dim lastRow ,xl
    With wb

         objSheet.Range("P1").Autofilter 16, Criteria1 ="=*sim*" 
         LastRow = objSheet.usedrange.rows.count
        If lastRow > 2 Then
           ' objSheet.Range(objSheet.Range("O2"), objSheet.Range("O" & lastRow)). _
               'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "SIMEX"
               objSheet.Range("O" & LastRow).Value = "SIMEX"


        End If

          WScript.Echo vbCrLf _
           & "LastRow:-" _
        '.Range("P:P").AutoFilter Field:=16 'clear the filter
    End With
```

Actual result like:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3
asd    sim       sim
dfg    P2P       sim
fgh    sim       sim
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is, so there's no way to know what you need help with.  Although your `With wb` statement is pointless as you don't refer to any child of the `wb` object, or assign it to anything, same with `objSheet` - it's not assigned to anything either.

Comment: wb is Active workbook and problem is that code run but value of column "P" is sim not getting and also simex value not fill in column "o"

Comment: Try and run your code in Break mode by Pressing F8 in the VBA window and see if Filter is being applied correctly and if code skips the If Condition.

Comment: Yes..code run in VBA but not shown filtered column with "sim"